# Preserve hyperlinks while exporting PDF from Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have inserted hyperlinks in Photoshop slices, and now I want to export the file as PDF, with clickable images. When I Save as PDF, hyperlinks are gone and images are not clickable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that indesign allows for saving .pdf documents in either print or web format. the latter allows for hyperlinks to be available. If photoshop does not offer this you can always add them in acrobat (not reader) and then resave the .pdf

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the hyperlinks were attached to text or graphic elements in the document --- when you rasterized the document to a graphic in PhotoShop these were flattened into your pixel map.

Instead of doing this, open the image in Adobe Acrobat, Export all the pixel images, edit those, then replace the original images in Acrobat.

Or, just get the source document and work w/ that instead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it can't be done, best chance you've got is to export the pdf from Photoshop into Acrobat and add it from there, it's the easiest thing in the world to do.